# ofstream issue: writing data stops if the file has been externally opened

Tags: c++, ofstream

I suppose my issue is quite stupid but I'm not a professional programmer. 
I've customized an already existing software for machine and process control for the company where I'm currently employed.

In particular, I wrote some code to obtain a log file containing the most important information about the producion process.
I'm using C++ and MFC libraries. I've used the ofstream class, and its functions. In particular I create the data file once in the creator of the class, and the I use the `.open (filename, ios::out | ios::app);` function in order to append information to it.

The code works well, but if I copy the log file before the end of the execution of the program (for example at the half of our production process, when I'd like to know the state of the system), it ends to writing and updating the data. Can you give me an axplanation of this and a possible solution for my issue?

Thank you so much

Comment: Just a guess - the copying might open the file in a mode that disallows sharing. So if you attempt to write *during* the copying the write might fail and set the stream to an error state.

Comment: I'd look into file locking solutions like [LockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx)